# how to combine values from multiple rows into a single row in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have excel sheet with multi data rows like this
[image: image1]

I want to sum values for duplicated item like this
[image: image2]

Comment: A pivot table would do this. Would you be able to use that?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately i have no experience in that

Comment: OK - your question seems like it is perfect for a pivot table. Also, because you are using Excel-2007, it is hard to find another approach that would do what you want. Have a look at this tutorial. Pivots are easy to learn and super powerful - it is one of the primary uses of Excel. https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

*ٱلسَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمْ*

*peace be with you*

---

Screenshot below (**B**) /[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98Td9ZM402I1ZbhkZ?e=kiXy53) refer -

There are plenty of ways to do this (a pivot table can be cumbersome due to relatively 'static' nature, lack versatility whenever heading labels are changed, and are hardly necessary).

I assume you have Office 365 compatible version of excel (although it's not essential, see bottom/appendix)

**SCREENSHOT** - Office 365 comptability

[image]

**FUNCTIONS**

```
=SUMIFS(C$5:C$13,$B$5:$B$13,$G5)
```

This will populate column H - you'll need to customise the formula so that it can be applied to your setup (e.g. move referenced cells/regions as req.)

You can drag this to the right/down to complete the tables as req

**OLDER VERSIONS**

Office 365 compatible version of Excel not essential, this is only used for Key (G col).  If you have older version then manually create the key in this column.  You can do this by copying the key from B:B, pasting into G:G, the selecting 'remove duplicates', Data -> Remove duplicates, per screenshot below.

Other functions/formula, H:I, remain unchanged are do not depend upon version (unless you using some dinosaur version before 10 or so years ago - i.e. before 'sumifs' was available)..

[image: Remove Duplicates - only if not using Office 365 compatible version of Excel]

Comment: (PS - this will sum everything - it won't ignore unique values in the original/long data table (where as I 'ought to' if I were being strict with my interpretation of you question...)